# Could not find "store" error in connected component nested in Dialog

Tags: redux, react-redux, dialog, material-ui, store

I have a connected component that will render fine when wrapped with a `<div>`, but when I wrap with Dialog component, I keep getting the dreaded: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(MyComponent)". Yes, the root `<App />` is wrapped with `<Provider />` and the store is fine, all other pages, components, connected items have access to store, just not when rendered in this Dialog.

This has not been a problem in the past, and was obviously hosed as a side effect from some dependency maintenance that was occurring. If I swap the Dialog component's underlying lib from MUI 0.20 to version 3 (via @material-ui/core/Dialog) it works fine. There's something going on with a balance between mui 0.20 and updated react-ish dependencies.

Just wondering if anyone has experienced this?

```
// Where it's invoked...

<ParentPageComp>
  <Dialog open>
    <MyConnectedComponent />
  </Dialog>
</ParentPageComp>

// What is being attempted to render...

class MyConnectedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Yeppers</div>;
  }
 }

export default connect(state => ({ blah: state.blah }))(MyConnectedComponent);
```

Again, if I replace `<Dialog>` with `<div>`, all is normal.

Not sure if this is relevant, but the parent components wrapping the Dialog are async loaded with hooks... even when replacing with code splitting mechanism of react-loadable, I get the same naughty results.

Using:

- Material-ui 0.20.2 (yes, the old one)
- React 16.8.6
- Redux 4.0.1
- React-redux 7.1.0
- React-router-dom 5.0.0

Comment: If you can reproduce this in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) it will make it easier for someone to try to help.

Comment: RenderToLayer (used by [Dialog](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v0.x/src/Dialog/Dialog.js#L488)) looks like a potential source of the problem: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v0.x/src/internal/RenderToLayer.js#L110

Comment: Looks like a good reason to upgrade Material-UI.

Comment: upgrade for sure... it's overdue, just balancing hours. For now I have the newer version of cherry picked components running alongside the legacy version components

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Old version can easily block context propagation thru DOM hierarchy. You can manually carry context over `<Dialog/>` component like this

```
import { Provider, ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';

//...
render() {
    return (
        <ParentPageComp>
            <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
                {((ctx) => (
                    <Dialog open>
                        <Provider store={ctx.store}>  /* make store available again */
                            <MyConnectedComponent />
                        </Provider>
                    </Dialog>
                )).bind(this) // Dont forget to bind this
                }
            </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
        </ParentPageComp>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton, this was it... while I am upgrading bit by bit, this explained exactly what was going on and helped me understand. I'll be able to push a new test version today thanks to your help

Comment: This solution works for me without bind this (eslint no-extra-bind). Our team discovered this issue after upgrading our app from react-redux v5.x to 7.1.0. We had no issues using the Dialog components before.